# Generate random non-repeating numbers in a range except specific numbers

Tags: python, random

I need to generate random numbers in Python. The result should be in this form:

```
(9, 15)
(6, 11)
(2, 2)
(17, 15)
(18, 3)
```

Where the first number in line - non-repeating random number in a range 1..20 except 3 and 5, the second number - any random number in a range 1...15

I was able to generate random numbers with exclusions, but I don't know how to exclude duplicates from results for the first number in line:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    from random import choice
    mm = choice([i for i in range(1, 21) if i not in [3, 5]])
    nn = random.randint(1, 15)
    result = mm, nn
    print(result)
```

So I get something like this:

```
(9, 15)
(17, 11)
(2, 2)
(17, 15)
(18, 3)
```

In the example given, the number 17 should not appear more than once.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: maybe you should get all values at once `numbers = sample(..., k=5)` (before loop) and later use `mm = numbers[i]`.

Comment: Put the valid first numbers in an array: [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, ... 20]. Then shuffle the array and take them in the shuffled order. They will not repeat until all 18 have been taken. Then reshuffle.

Comment: Thanks for help! Your suggestions to do it before the loop are much easier to implement